# What is a good linear algebra book for game programmers?

Tags: mathematics, books, linear-algebra

I was told that I should start learning Linear Algebra in order to create good games with good physics.

I'm reading Linear Algebra book and it's completely foreign to me. The author starts out with solving linear equations (two equations, two variables) and I remember learning about that in school, but almost immediately he jumps into other things that seem to be taken directly from the Necronomicon.

What book can I read to learn some good math, but starting from the fundamentals?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: https://amzn.to/3h6ksNv For beginners is best, no1 maths book from Springer publisher, even I too dont have any CS or maths background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sergio you might want to aim more toward a Game Development math book like

[**Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications, Second Edition: A Programmer's Guide**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123742978)

Instead of the classical Linear Algebra you would learn in college.  Also like Ron Warholic said, stating what your math comfort level is would better help us taylor a specific book.

Comment: +1,  highly recommended.  This book is "anchoring" a lot of the fundamental concepts in ways they never were before.

Answer (score 16):

Not a book, but you should check out the math curriculum over at the [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/). I'm in the process of using these videos to brush up on my own math skills. They cover an extremely broad range of material, and the author has been praised for his teaching style.

IMO, truly an amazing resource.

[http://www.khanacademy.org/#Linear Algebra](http://www.khanacademy.org/#Linear%20Algebra)

Comment: I agree entirely, that looks amazing.

Comment: Thank you for adding the link to Khan Academy,It is going to be very useful to me. +1 for this reply.

Answer (score 2):

What level of math are you at? Do you understand things like vectors and matrices?  What about geometry and trigonometry?

I have [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584502770) 2nd edition by Eric Lengyel and it's a great refresher on math related to games.  It starts with a very basic introduction to linear algebra with vectors and matrices and works through more advanced things like illumination, visibility determination, computational geometry, and game physics systems.

The only downside from a programmers point of view is that it is very equation heavy.  If you are the type that gets scared or frustrated by equations I would look elsewhere for reference.

The one thing you need to make sure to do regardless of the book you choose is to do the exercises!  You can't learn unless you actually do them.  For fun you could even implement them to allow you to see how the math maps to code.

Answer (score 2):

Frank D. Luna provides a brief but comprehensive introduction to the applicable concepts of linear algebra in his books on game development with Direct3D. You might want to take a look at his latest book, [*Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 10*](http://d3dcoder.net/d3d10.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Best world class course in linear algebra is [MIT's one](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm) with the great Gilbert Strang

It is about 34 lectures

You may face few calculus examples which you can ignore them

check the syllabus for his text

Answer (score 1):

I really liked Eric Lengyel's [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584502770). It's been my constant desk companion since school.